# Graph created inside of a <div> seems to be larger then the <div> itself and overlaps

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `Canvas.js` to create graphs, and I placed one inside of a `<div>`, and it overlaps on the bottom two sides. I have tried creating another `<div>` inside the initial one to no avail.

Here is the relevant html:

```
<div class="box" id="gdpbox">
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        var gdpChart = new CanvasJS.Chart("gdpbox", {
        title: {
            text: "Gross Domestic Product"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: [

                //I took out about 500 data points, these are just for reference

                { x: new Date(2013,07,01), y: 15779.9}, 
                { x: new Date(2013,10,01), y: 15916.2}, 
                { x: new Date(2014,01,01), y: 15831.7}, 
                { x: new Date(2014,04,01), y: 15985.7},

            ]
        }]
    });
    gdpChart.render();
    gdpChart = {};    
        </script>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS for box:

```
.box{
    /*
    height:40%;
    width:35%;
    */
}
```

and for gdpbox:

```
#gdpbox{    
    border: solid #60C3B1;
    position:absolute; 
    margin: 5% 13% auto;
}
```

Here is what the graph currently looks like:
[image: Overlapping Graph]

It should be enclosed in the teal box.

Hopefully this is detailed enough to show what I'm doing wrong. I can provide more details if needed.

I realized that the default graph size is 500px, and that is what is causing it to overlap.  But now I cannot figure out how to fit the graph inside of my box, because the box does not have a set size.

Comment: A jsfiddle or codepen would help solve this issue. I assume you've tried CSS styles for #gdpbox, not just the inner div? I think you should remove the inner div, in any case.

Comment: oh, duh. nm. I see you have. A codepen would still help though. Are you using `box-sizing: border-box`?